# Use of createWindow method in Titanium using Android

Tags: android, view, titanium, emulation

please give me code which contain views.For example: red,green,blue.

```
var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                backgroundColor:'red',
                title: 'My Root Window'
        });

window.open();
```

I am using this to create main Window.It gives force close error when I execute this on emulator.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you want? Please improve your question if you actually deserve an answer.

Comment: i want a demo for window , which contain another two view.

Comment: use the show() method to make the view visible. You can use the add() to create a child to the view

Comment: please give me full code ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Create a fullscreen window with a red background.

```
var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

   backgroundColor:'red'

});

window.open({fullscreen:true});
```

Click on  **[link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.1/Titanium.UI.Window-object)**   for more references.

Answer (score 0):

app.js:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: 'horizontal'
    title: 'My Root Window'
});

var views = new Array();
var backgrounds = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];

for(var i in backgrounds) {
    views.push(Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor: backgrounds[i],
        height: '33%'
    }));
}

for(var i in views) {
    win.add(views[i]);
}

win.open();
```

Comment: it will also display error like 'Unfortunately, has stopped !

Comment: Do you have possibility to run it in iPhone emulator? It must be something wrong with your Titanium SDK or Android SDK setup. Try to delete everything in your `build/android` folder and run your app again..

Comment: i am write this code in ui/common/FirstView.js is this correct or not ?

Comment: anything write in FirstView.js ?

Comment: it doesn't matter in this simple example. This will work also without FirstView.js, but normally you should put window logic into separate file. Read more about it here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium .

Comment: please set the answer as accepted to close this issue.